# Etale fundamental group

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In the case of trivial fibration $X \times Z \to Z$ the etale fundamental group is the product of the fundamental groups of the fiber times the fundamental group of the base. Is there some possible genralization to the case of general fibration?

Comment: There is a long exact sequence (which is not that long, iirc) for the étale fund. group.

Comment: Yes please tell me about it, where can I find it? Thank you

Comment: Well, I googled for it and found a few useful documents. Have you tried?

Comment: Do you mean the article by Friedlander?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reference you are looking for is SGA 1, X.

Corollary 1.4 gives a sequence in this situation. Suppose $f: X\to Y$ proper, separable, $Y$ is connected, and $f_*(\mathcal{O}_X)=\mathcal{O}_Y$ (in particular, we have geometrically connected fibers). Let $F=\overline{X}_y$ be a geometric fiber. In this case, the natural sequence

$$\pi_1(F)\to \pi_1(X)\to \pi_1(Y)\to 0$$

is exact. It is possible to derive the theorem about a product you mention from this one.

Comment: I read in Friedlander a longer exact sequence with $\pi_n$ for $n >1$. Is it not in the algebra-geometric context?

Comment: @user48900 I would imagine people have defined higher etale $\pi_n$. I would also imagine that if such things were defined "correctly" then the sequence would continue. That is outside of what I've ever seen, so someone else will need to answer that. Note this sequence does start with $\pi_0$ on the right, but we assumed $F$ connected to get a $0$ there.